# How to disable compiler message in python2?

Tags: python

I'm compiling some python codes with `python2` (Python 2.7.6). I am using the following command:

```
python2 -m compileall $DIRETORIO$FONTE
```

But it is outputing the message below every time I compile my code:

```
Compiling Python/File.py ...
```

How can I disable this message? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the `-q` switch. From the `-h` command-line help option for the `compileall` script:

```
-q: output only error messages
```

or from the [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compileall.html):

> `-q`
>   Do not print the list of files compiled, print only error messages.

Applying that to your command line:

```
python2 -m compileall -q $DIRETORIO$FONTE
```

This still will output error messages. On Python 3, you can specify `-q` twice (use `-q -q` or `-qq`) to suppress *all* output.

Comment: I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer, to deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answer!

Answer (score 0):

From [compileall — Byte-compile Python librarie](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compileall.html) (or typing `python -m compileall --help`):

> -q
>
> Do not print the list of files compiled, print only error messages.

The `-q` has to be written after `compileall` keyword. Code above can be update as follows:

```
python2 -m compileall -q $DIRETORIO$FONTE
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. :-)